# Group references with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

I am using BibTeX to maintain my references.

I have a lot of books in my `.bib` file, but some of the books are my primary sources.

Is it possible to group my references into 'primary sources' and 'secondary sources'?

What I am looking for is to choose to which group each bibtex entry belongs, and then print the grouped references instead of just the default references.

Comment: Have a look at the [Multiple bibliographies?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/FAQ-multbib.html) entry in the UK TeX FAQ archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [multibib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib?lang=en) package. It's difficult to give you a minimal working example, because you would need your `.bib` files and the `multibib.sty` to compile, but it would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{PS}{Primary Sources}
\newcommand{\bibfile}{/path/to/your/bibfile} 

\begin{document}

The best book to read is \citePS{citation1}. 
Some secondary stuff to look at is \cite{citation2}.

\bibliographystylePS{plain}
\bibliographyPS{\bibfile}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\bibfile}

\end{document}
```

Then if the file containing this is called `example.tex`, you compile like this:

```
latex example
bibtex example
bibtex PS
latex example
latex example
```

See also e.g. [these posts](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=6909).