# Two slides with references in beamer with BibTeX

Tags: beamer, bibtex, natbib, multibib

I'm preparing a `beamer` for a talk and I would like to include some bibliography at the end.

My idea was to include two different slides, one with the basic bibliography and other with extra references.

I haven't had no idea of how I could do it, but I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342888/group-references-with-bibtex) that also cites [these posts](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=6909).

The question suggests to use `multibib` package. And that is what I have done. However, I can't achieve the desired result. The problem is that the first part doesn't produce any reference.

Here is my `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl,aeguill}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justifying text

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{dk}{bibliography}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\lipsum[1]

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Selected bibliography}

\bibliographystyledk{plain}
\bibliographydk{bibliography}
\nocitedk{Courant:dirac_manifolds}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Other bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\nocite{Gualtieri:thesis}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I include my `bibliography.bib` file too:

```
@article {Courant:dirac_manifolds,
    AUTHOR = {Courant, Theodore James},
     TITLE = {Dirac manifolds},
   JOURNAL = {Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  FJOURNAL = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
    VOLUME = {319},
      YEAR = {1990},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {631--661},
      ISSN = {0002-9947},
   MRCLASS = {58F05 (53C57)},
  MRNUMBER = {998124},
MRREVIEWER = {Patrick Iglesias},
       DOI = {10.2307/2001258},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.2307/2001258},
}

@article {Gualtieri:thesis,
    AUTHOR = {Gualtieri, Marco},
     TITLE = {Generalized complex geometry},
   JOURNAL = {Ann. of Math. (2)},
  FJOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics. Second Series},
    VOLUME = {174},
      YEAR = {2011},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {75--123},
      ISSN = {0003-486X},
   MRCLASS = {53D18},
  MRNUMBER = {2811595},
MRREVIEWER = {Frederik Witt},
       DOI = {10.4007/annals.2011.174.1.3},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2011.174.1.3},
}
```

Thanks in advance.

PD. I guess the problem may be in the `\nocite` command for the first bibliography but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see that the packages in `\usepackage{ae,aecompl,aeguill}` are outdated. Please do not use them!

After compiling your given code with

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

you have with `multibib` to run in your case two times `bibtex`:

```
bibtex mwe.aux
bibtex dk.aux
```

because the code

```
\bibliographydk{bibliography}
\nocitedk{Courant:dirac_manifolds}
```

creates a second bib file `dk.bib` you need to run with bibtex ...

Run

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

twice and see the following resulting bibliographies:

[image]

and

[image]

Because I did not change your code I omitted to include it here ...

Comment: Thanks. it would never have occurred to me to do that. By the way, is there an alternative for `\usepackage{ae,aecompl,aeguill}`?